# primeNG datatable - excel like filter

Tags: angular, primeng

**ORIGINAL (may 20)**

I am using PrimeNG beta6 with Angular2 RC.

I my sample of p-dataTable, I have enabled column filter using [filter]="true" but this just give normal text filter option.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="products" [rows]="2" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" >
    <header>List of products</header>
    <p-column field="productName" header="productName" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="productCode" header="productCode" [filter]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="releaseDate" header="releaseDate" [filter]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="description" header="description"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

How do I apply excel like filter on this?

---

**EDIT (July 10):**

I have updated my application to PrimeNG beta 9 with Angular 2 RC4 version

p-dataTable filters looks like below-
[image]

However, excel filters are looks like below-
[image]

Anyone has idea How do I apply excel like filter on primeNG datatable?

Comment: have you tried `[sortable]="true"`

Comment: yes... refer productName column in above code

Answer (score 0):

Probably with a MultiSelect Filter !

```
<p-dataTable [value]="products" [rows]="2" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" >
    <header>List of products</header>
    <p-column field="productName" header="productName" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="productCode" header="productCode" [filter]="true">
 <ng-template pTemplate="filter">
            <p-multiSelect [options]="SelectedItemObject"
                           appendTo="body"
                           defaultLabel="SelectProduct"
                           styleClass="ui-column-filter"
            ></p-multiSelect>
        </ng-template>
</p-column>
    <p-column field="releaseDate" header="releaseDate" [filter]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="description" header="description"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

refer to primeNg for multiSelect info ! 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect